# Constrains on specific bits in integer

Tags: specman

I want to gen b (uint) with the following constrain:
If a has zero in specific bit I want be to have zero in the same bit.

I tried this:

```
!a , !b : uint(bits:4);
gen a; gen b;
for i from 0 to 3 {
  keep read_only(a[i:i] == 0) => b[i:i] == 0;
}:
```

I got this error:`gen action "Constraint does not contain any generative element"`

Comment: The error message is a bit misleading. The syntax `keep for i from 0 to 3` does not exist to my knowledge.

Comment: What's the exact syntax that you tried to use? The example shown seems like a mix between variables (or fields) declarations, "gen" procedural actions and "keep" declarative constraints, and also "keep for i from ... to" is not a legal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

are a and b really generated on the fly, in different "gen" action?
if they are generated together, you can try something like this -

```
   a  : uint(bits:4);
b  : uint(bits:4);

all_bits : list of int;
keep all_bits == {0; 1; 2; 3};
keep for each (i) in all_bits  {
    read_only(a[i:i] == 0) => b[i:i] == 0;
};
```